# South Ossetia visa

Tags: visas, georgia-country, south-ossetia

I would like to visit south Ossetia and north Ossetia. I will be arriving in Georgia first .. What is easy way to get Ossetia Visa ?  and how i suppose to get in ossetia from Georgia (train ? taxi) 
I'm From Canada

Comment: Welcome to travel.stackexchange. I am not an expert in South Ossetia but the Wikitravel article https://wikitravel.org/en/South_Ossetia has some information about your questions.

Comment: Georgia considers South Ossetia part of its territory, so you won't be able to enter from Georgia, much less obtain a "visa" for it there. I strongly recommend you do some reading on recent history of the region and consult travel guides and websites first, returning here to hone your plans once you have a basic understanding of the dynamics. I further recommend you take the site [tour] and review the [help] for a better understanding of how Stack Exchange works, and the kinds of questions we can answer here.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to enter South Ossetia from Georgia.

To my knowledge, it is only possible to enter and leave South Ossetia by land to/from Russia (no flights). Accordingly, a multiple entry visa to Russia is required.

According to the [South Ossetian Ministry of Foreign Affairs](http://www.mfa-rso.su/node/55), visas are not required for anyone.

There is also an [invitation requirement (among others)](http://www.mfa-rso.su/taxonomy/term/13) for entry to South Ossetia.

(Please use Google translate on the above links if you do not speak Russian - it does a good job!)